# joining two matrices of different sizes by row name in r

Tags: r, join, matrix, dimensions

I've seen a few questions asked about this, but I wasn't able to understand any of the answers and they all seem to be closed threads.

What I'm looking to do is join two matrices which have different dimensions, but have two common columns. If any two rows in the two matrices have the same values in two columns I want to then append those two rows, otherwise I want to add the row to the bottom of the matrix.

For example: Matrix 1

```
Matrix 1
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
a     b    c    d
e     f    g    h
i     j    k    l

Matrix 2
Col1 Col3 Col5
a    c    e
g    f    m
```

In the above example, the first row in Matrices 1 and two have the same entries in Col1 and Col3, while rows 2 and 3 are dissimilar.

I would like the output to look as follows:

```
NewMatrix
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
a     b   c    d    e
e     f   g    h    0
i     j   k    l    0
g     0   f    0    m
```

So that the matching rows are joined, while any rows that don't match are simply added on to the end.

Would anyone have an idea of how to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: I'm on my phone right now so I won't post an answer, but have you looked at merge?

Comment: @AnandaMahto 
I have tried it, but I had some trouble getting it to work. I used this:
`merge(Matrix1,Matrix2,by.Matrix1=c(Matrix1[,1],Matrix1[,3]),by.Matrix2 = c(Matrix2[,1],Matrix2[,2]))`

(Sorry, I'm not sure how to enter as code in a comment?) 
but it results in a 0 by 0 matrix, even though there are definite overlaps between the two matrices.
Thanks for the help

Comment: @AnandaMahto 
  Thanks for your help, I managed to get it to work using merge, I just had a slight syntax error in the message above.
  
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Mike it would help others if you could kindly share your solution.

Comment: Mike, as @zx8754 mentions, please post your ultimate solution as an answer and (when SO lets you) *accept* it. This helps others coming with similar questions quickly see that there is a possible answer available that might apply to their situation.

Comment: Ok sure thing. 
   `a = merge(Matrix1,Matrix2,by.Matrix2= 
     c(Matrix2[,1],Matrix2$[,3]),
      by.Matrix1=c(Matrix1$[,1],Matrix1[,3]),
        all = TRUE)`

Comment: @Mike, you can't accept a comment :) -- See the big box that says "your answer"? Write your answer there and accept it by checking on the hollow checkmark when SO lets you do so, which might be after some time since SO makes you wait to accept your own answer (I think).

Comment: @AnandaMahto
Ok thanks, I think I did it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a <- merge(Matrix1, Matrix2, 
           by.Matrix2 = c(Matrix2[,1], Matrix2$[,3]),
           by.Matrix1 = c(Matrix1[,1], Matrix1[,3]),
           all = TRUE)
```

**Update**, much cleaner version from @Ananda:

```
a <- merge(Matrix1, Matrix2, by = c("Col1", "Col3"), all = TRUE)
```

Comment: I *think* this would be more direct: `merge(Matrix1, Matrix2, by = c("Col1", "Col3"), all = TRUE)`. Here, `by = c("Col1", "Col3")` passes the names of the columns in common between the two matrices. By the way, now you should be able to *accept* your answer too :-)